# Wix: I can't use some tags :/

Tags: installation, wix

I want to create installer in Wix. I use 3.5 version integrated with VS2008 Professional.
I need detect MS SQL Server installation (I do it) and eventually install it. I try to use bootstrapper, there is code:

```
    <ItemGroup>
      <BootstrapperFileMax Include="Microsoft.Sql.Server.Express.9.2">
        <ProductName>SQL Server 2005 Express Edition</ProductName>
      </BootstrapperFileMax>
    </ItemGroup>
```

Compiler return me that error:

***Error 2:The Product element contains an unexpected child element 'ItemGroup'.***

Maybe I need some references? Should I publish all code?

Thanks for all your help.
Jacek

Answer (score 2):

A WiX product element can not contain an ItemGroup, as the error suggests.

See here for a description of the Product element and it's valid children.

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_product.htm

Bootstrapper code is normally added to the msbuild file (.csproj file) rather then the wix .wxs file, which I think might be where you placed it - see here for a description of how to do so:

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm

If that doesn't resolve your issue, perhaps add the entire contents of your .wxs and .wxproj files to the question - this should provide enough context to assist people in resolving your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the ItemGroup tag is not placed correctly. Here's a brief example:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.2.0">
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0</ProductName>
    </BootstrapperFile>
    <BootStrapperFile Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.8.0">
      <ProductName>Microsoft Report Viewer</ProductName>
    </BootStrapperFile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Bootstrapper">
    <GenerateBootstrapper
      ApplicationFile="WixBootstrapSample.msi"
      ApplicationName="Wix Sample"
      BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)"
      OutputPath=".\"
      ComponentsLocation="HomeSite"
      Culture="en"
    />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The example is from [wixwiki](http://www.wixwiki.com/index.php?title=Main_Page). A more detailed description about how to deploy additional components you can find [here](http://www.wixwiki.com/index.php?title=Deploying_Additional_Components).

Comment: wixwiki links are dead, it is now a dating site . . . I don't advise clicking on them.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'BootStrapperFile' and not BootstrapperFileMax.

I am using BootStrapperFile and its working fine.

SQL Server 2005 Express Edition